# How to get latest n record for per group in Django Orm

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm, django-rest-framework

i got 3 models like

```
class Business(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    ...

class Dude(models.Model):
    ...

class PhoneNumber(models.Model):
    dude = models.ForeignKey(Dude)
    date = models.DatetimeField()
    business = models.ForeignKey(Business)
```

I want to get last 3 phone numbers of each dude and this is how i achived it;

```
response=list()
for dude in Dude.objects.all():
    temp_dude = dict()
    temp_dude['name_label'] = str(dude.name)
    temp_dude['phones'] = list()
    for phone_number in PhoneNumber.objects.filter(dude=dude).order_by("-date")[:3]:
        temp_phone = dict()
        temp_phone['date_added'] = phone_number.date.timestamp()
        temp_phone['business_label'] = str(phone_number.business.name)
        temp_dude['phones'].append(temp_phone)
    response.append(temp_dude)
```

but its hitting database at least 2 time for every dude and consuming lots of cpu.

what is the most efficent way for getting same response with django orm?

P.S : I got 30 million phone number and 170 dude in total.

Comment: tried ordering in the model class?

Comment: The problem is not getting the items but following the foreign key in the loop. Try https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-related !

Comment: One of the problems is that in MySQL there is no straightforward way to limit *per group*. Yes you can do it with some hacking, but there is no special syntax for that.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I'm using postgresql but i want to achive this with orm if I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to try in this situation is a `select_related` to fetch the phone_number for each dude.

```
dudes = Dude.objects.select_related('phone_number', 'phone_number__business').all()
for dude in dudes:
    do_the_thing()
```

(note the `select_related` on the other object you're querying too, `phone_number.business`)

In this case, if you have lots of `phone_number`s per `Dude`, then this might perform worse than your original query, as it will grab every Dude.phone_number.

Unfortunately, as the comments have suggested, there's no ORM way to limit the `select_related`. You'll need to write some SQL. You can get a head-start by observing what SQL Django generated for the select_related query by turning up [DB kogging](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/logging/#django-db-backends), and then running your own [custom SQL query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/sql/).